# R DT datatable format digits row-wise with formatRound

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, dt

I am facing the following issue : I would like to format a datatable with R package DT in a Shiny App. I would like that in the 1st row numbers are rounded to 0 digit, and to 2 digits in the other rows

```
data <- data.frame(c1 = c(123.456, 789.123, 456.55),
c2 = c(123.456, 789.123, 456.55))
# this does not work
datatable(data) %>% formatRound(1:2, digits=0, rows=1) %>% formatRound(1:2, digits=2, rows=1:2)
# this also does not work
datatable(data) %>% formatRound(1:2,digits=c(0,2,2))
```

Can you help me ? Is it possible to achieve this ? I guess probably with some JS it should be possible but I am newbie to js...

thanks in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 0):

Although not so efficient for large datasets, what you could try, if your dataset is not very large (else it might be slow to produce output):

```
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(c1 = c(123.456, 789.123, 456.55),
                   c2 = c(123.456, 789.123, 456.55))

formatRows <- function(df) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        if (i == 1) {
            df[i, 1:2] <- round(df[i, 1:2], 0)
        } else {
            df[i, 1:2] <- round(df[i, 1:2], 2)
        }
    }
    return(df)
}

#apply the func
formattedData <- formatRows(data)

#convert into a datatable
datatable(formattedData)
```

result:

[image]

And shiny app, could be something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

formatRows <- function(df) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        if (i == 1) {
            df[i, 1:2] <- round(df[i, 1:2], 0)
        } else {
            df[i, 1:2] <- round(df[i, 1:2], 2)
        }
    }
    return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- data.frame(
        c1 = c(123.456, 789.123, 456.55),
        c2 = c(123.456, 789.123, 456.55)
    )

    formattedData <- formatRows(data)

    output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(formattedData)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thansk but i was looking for a solution that does not modify the dataframe itself...

Comment: It will modify the dataset only in reactive stage but original database is not changed. Still, could specify this in details using example please

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to do with `formatRound`. You can do that with a JavaScript `rowCallback`:

```r
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "function(row, data, displayNum, displayIndex, dataIndex) {",
  "  if(displayIndex === 0) {",
  "    $('td:eq(1)', row).html(data[1].toFixed(0));",
  "    $('td:eq(2)', row).html(data[2].toFixed(0));",
  "  } else {",
  "    $('td:eq(1)', row).html(data[1].toFixed(2));",
  "    $('td:eq(2)', row).html(data[2].toFixed(2));",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

dat <- data.frame(
  c1 = c(123.456, 789.123, 456.55),
  c2 = c(123.456, 789.123, 456.55)
)

datatable(dat, options = list(rowCallback = JS(js)))
```